# Creating shapefile layer with OSGeo4W shell

Tags: gdal, ogr, osgeo4w

I want to create an new empty shapefile with OSGeo4W shell.

Is there a command line like:

```
gdal_create -f "ESRI Shapefile" -wkt "point" -srs "EPSG:31256" -o output.shp
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such create option in GDAL tools but a proper solution would require writing a few lines of Python code. Best workaround that comes into my mind is to select data from any existing data source with point geometries by using SQL that finds nothing.

```
ogr2ogr -of "ESRI Shapefile" -sql "select geometry from test where 1=2" emptytest.shp test.shp

ogrinfo emptytest.shp -al
INFO: Open of `emptytest.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: emptytest
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2020-01-21
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 0
Extent: (0.000000, 0.000000) - (0.000000, 0.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCRS["MGI / Austria GK East",
    BASEGEOGCRS["MGI",
        DATUM["Militar-Geographische Institut",
            ELLIPSOID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4312]],
    CONVERSION["Austria Gauss-Kruger East",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",16.3333333333333,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",-5000000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["northing (X)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["easting (Y)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["Austria - east of 14┬░50'E"],
        BBOX[46.56,14.83,49.02,17.17]],
    ID["EPSG",31256]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
```

An empty shapefile of the same type as the source data (point), with CRS EPSG:31256, and with no features nor attributes was created.